# JVM tries to load a class that isn't called

Tags: java

I am writing code that adds functions to a 'mod' if it exists in the classpath (referenced by `pixelmonPresent`)

```
PixelHammerTool extends ItemHammer
```

, `ItemHammer` only exists if `pixelmon` is present

The issue im having is, if i do this in the class (same package)

```
if(Basemod.pixelmonPresent) {
rubyHammer = new PixelHammerTool(Basemod.RUBY, "pixelutilitys:RubyHammer", "rubyHammer");
}
```

It will cause a class not found on `PixelHammerTool`,
Why is this being called if the if statement is false and what can i do about it ?

Comment: Compile time vs Runtime?

Comment: At compiletime the class is present.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The why is simple and straightforward: because when a class is loaded, all the classes referenced by it are loaded too. (In fact they are loaded first.)

Avoiding it isn't too complicated either, although the code won't look nice: you need to load the class with reflection, using [`Class.forName()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName(java.lang.String)), find the constructor you want from the array returned by `Class.getConstructors()` and then create an instance using `Constructor.newInstance()`.

Note that while if it only happens a few times in your code, this solution is fine, if you find yourself doing this a lot then you should probably look for a dependency injection framework that will do the heavy lifting for you.

Answer (score 2):

Under the [Linking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4) section in the specs, we see this:

> For example, a Java Virtual Machine implementation may choose to resolve each symbolic reference in a class or interface individually when it is used ("lazy" or "late" resolution), or to resolve them all at once when the class is being verified ("eager" or "static" resolution). This means that the resolution process may continue, in some implementations, after a class or interface has been initialized. Whichever strategy is followed, any error detected during resolution must be thrown at a point in the program that (directly or indirectly) uses a symbolic reference to the class or interface.

So when the constant has to be defined is implementation-dependent, based on the class loader. The behavior you're seeing is consistent with the "eager" resolution mentioned: when you reference `PixelHammerTool` in your code, *even if it's for a runtime path that will never be hit*, the class loader tries to link in its definition, which does not exist.

This strategy causes the JVM to start slower but execute faster at runtime, which is generally the strategy taken in all the implementations I'm familiar with. Indeed, the default class loader is given the name "bootstrap class loader" because it has this behavior - load classes at JVM bootstrap time.

You can either instantiate the class via reflection, as biziclop suggested (the easier route), which forces linking at runtime, or find or create a class loader that instantiates classes lazily.